# How Viewport works in css

Tags: html, css, viewport

I am working in css and using media jqueries to make a responsive web design. In my tutorial on w3schools, they add the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
```

but my page has no chaned effect even if I remove this tag.

I have created the following page [My Created Page Here](http://awresult.com), but `viewport` doesn't display as I expect.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Have you look at the page on a mobile device?